# Open multiple files for reading using the file naming format in Fortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I need help opening multiple files for reading one by one in Fortran. The code below has the right names for the files but overwrites the contents of the file before opening.

How can I stop this from happening

```
WRITE(FN,10)lam, zeta, (array(k)%str)!,k=1,N)
WRITE(6,*)FN!filename 
OPEN(1,FILE=FN, status='replace')
CLOSE(1)


10 FORMAT('4e3_2048_',(I3.0),'_',(I2.2),'_',(A3),'.ksz_cl.txt') !
```

Comment: I only want to open and read the data from the files @francescalus

Comment: Thanks @francescalus

Comment: Please don't completely change questions to ask follow-up or related questions.  For small clarifications, comments on answers are appropriate, but for larger re-writings like this it's better to ask a new question.  You can of course reference this question if you do ask another, to give any relevant background.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `status='replace'` when opening the files you cause them to be deleted and recreated (Fortran 2018 12.5.6.18):

> If REPLACE is specified and the file does exist, the file is deleted, a new file is created with the same name, and the status is changed to OLD.

That's not good when you want to read from the files.  Instead, use something like

```
open(1, file=FN, action='read', status='old', position='rewind')
```

to ensure: the file exists; it's opened for reading; is positioned at the start of the file.

I have seen `status='replace'` intended to mean that the *connection* is replaced, allowing the unit number to be reused.  As can be seen, that's not correct.  On that note: unit numbers can be happily reused once a connection is closed.  Indeed, if an `open` statement refers to a unit already connected to a different file, there's an implied `close` on that first connection.

Comment: Oh, and don't use unit numbers less than 10 in your code, as that might conflict with the preconnected units. Even better, use NEWUNIT= and let the compiler runtime allocate a free unit number for you.

Comment: Thanks @francescalus. I have a follow up question to this. I'm trying to read in multiple files in a loop but it appears my code reads the files each time which makes it slow. I have included a flag to read the files the first time only but itt doesn't seem to work. I've updated the code.